# why 'DEVNULL' and 'PIPE' from 'subprocess' were printed as '-3' and '-1'?

Tags: python, subprocess

Two values 'DEVNULL' and 'PIPE' for stdout and stderr respectively were printed as '-3' and '-1' when I put them into a dic. How to solve this problem except transform them into strings through adding '' symbols because they will be afterwards as arguments incorporated into a subprocess.run function.

```
from subprocess import DEVNULL, PIPE

F1 = DEVNULL
F2 = PIPE
L1 = {'stdout':F1, 'stderr':F2}

print(L1)
```

output

```
{'stdout': -3, 'stderr': -1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine, if you look into [`subprocess` source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py) you will find that

```
Constants
---------
DEVNULL: Special value that indicates that os.devnull should be used
PIPE:    Special value that indicates a pipe should be created
STDOUT:  Special value that indicates that stderr should go to stdout
```

and

```
PIPE = -1
STDOUT = -2
DEVNULL = -3
```

Example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['echo', '123'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

is equivalent to

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['echo', '123'], stdout=-3)
```

but 1st is less cryptic for someone reading such code

Comment: that is the reason why! new things learned, many thanks for the answer.